# sequelize unit-test mocking with postgres and sequelize-mock

Tags: node.js, postgresql, unit-testing, mocking, sequelize.js

I'm trying to do build unit-test with `sequelize-mock`, node and postgres, but whenever I query against my mock I'm getting results no matter if I got the current data in my mock or not. It's seems sequelize-mock is [automatically generated results](https://sequelize-mock.readthedocs.io/en/stable/docs/mock-queries/) based on my query. I tried to use `autoQueryFallback` option, but I'm getting `SequelizeMockEmptyQueryQueueError`.

for example:

```
describe('/GET/:email/exists', () => {
  it('it should check if email exists - it should fail', async () => {
    const email = 'somemail@mail.com';
    try {
      const res = await fakeDbUtil.isEmailExistsDb(email);
      chai.assert.equal(res, null);
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  });
});
```

I do not have the given email in my mock DB, so I expecting to get `null` result. However, I'm getting result containing my mock together with the current email (override my mock original email).

I don't sure if I'm doing something wrong?
**Are there some other good mocking frameworks out there which can work with postgres and sequelize?**

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `autoQueryFallback: true` option allows sequelize-mock to generate automatic results based on the Model properties. If you don't want the automated results you can declare `autoQueryFallback: false` when you are defining a model object or on the sequelizeMock object.

```
    const UserMock = SequelizeMock.define("user", {}, {
                          autoQueryFallback: false
                        });
```

To mock the data you can use Sequelize-mock QueryInterface to queue the results for a query.

So in your case, you can mock email something like below.

```
UserMock.$queueResult(UserMock.build({
  id: 2,
  email: "something@gmail.com"
}));
```

And then you can call your DB query function and expect the result.

```
const res = await fakeDbUtil.isEmailExistsDb(email);
expect(res.email).not.toBe("expectedEmail")
```

For more information about mocking sequelize model check [this](https://sequelize-mock.readthedocs.io/en/stable/docs/mock-queries/) out.

This test is more of a *Jest* framework way. It's a nice testing framework. If you want to give it a try, check out [this](https://jestjs.io/)